# With LDAP in JAVA, how to set The Kerberos AES support checkboxes correspond to the value set in an attribute called msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I want to set the "This account supports AES 128 encryption" checkbox in JAVA via LDAP. Has anyone done that?

[KerberosAEScheckbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTWiU.png)

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was trying to do it in Java, has anyone done it in Java? I have to method to create AD account in Java which is simple but I am not able to modify the msDSSupportedEncryption Types in Java

Answer (score 0):

These values are related to [msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/MsDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes) and [UF_USE_DES_KEY_ONLY](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/USE_DES_KEY_ONLY) bit (0x200000) in the UserAccountControl attribute of the DC and the Windows Clients.

There are two steps:

- Remove the UF_USE_DES_KEY_ONLY registry entry
- Setting the desired value for msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes

msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes is a a bitmask so values are additive. I believe "28" (as an integer) is probably the best value. ( which apparently corresponds to "RC4","AES128","AES256" )

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at an example where I can set that in Java.